# hamonics and sidebands in dc-dc converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, modeling, distortion

[The](http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch7slide.pdf) lecture (page 8) shows output voltage spectrum with sinusoidal modulation of duty cycle of a dc-dc converter.

I am wondering where the hamonics and sidebands come from.

For hamonics, I read somewhere that because converter power stage is non-linear 
so it generates hamonics. I can see it from the nonlinear static control-to-output characteristic of buck-boost converter below.

However, I don't see where switching hamonics and sidebands come from.

Could anyone explain why these hamonics and sidebands exist here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It comes from the ripple i.e. The triangular waveform around the sine wave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an unmodulated switching waveform is rectangular in nature and, as per any basic analysis of a square wave, it contains harmonics of the fundamental switching frequency: -

[image]

So, a square wave contains a series of sinewave harmonics starting at the fundamental switching frequency and extending, theoretically to infinity. Next, look at the top picture in the image below. This is the general case for a rectangular wave with the duty cycle as a variable: -

[image]

It tells us that harmonics can arise at all integer multiples of the fundamental switching frequency. As a side note, the special symmetrical case of a square wave happens to only contain odd numbered harmonics.

The question shows a sinusoidal base frequency altering (modulating) the PWM duty cycle in order to generate a PWM sinewave. This will produce sidebands either side of every generated harmonic. The distance in Hz from the centre of the harmonic to the centre of either sideband is twice the modulating frequency.

Analysing the sidebands is the real tricky bit to understand; you have to start by considering the formula for the n\$_{th}\$ harmonic: -

a\$_n\$ is proportional to \$\dfrac{2}{n} sin(n\pi d)\$

And, if d (the duty cycle) approaches zero (or unity) the "sin" term becomes zero i.e. the harmonics greatly reduces in amplitude. This happens at twice the modulating frequency i.e. all the harmonics are amplitude modulated at twice the frequency of the modulating waveform.

Because there are DC terms involved, this boils down to exactly the same analysis as a regular [AM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) broadcast: -

[image]

The wiki link above shows the full math behind AM and sidebands but it basically boils down to any one of the following trig identities: -

[image]

So, sum and difference frequencies are produced and it is these sum and difference frequencies that create the sidebands.

---

New section that hopefully demonstrates that a simple PWM circuit (based around an AD8605 op-amp, a 100 kHz triangle wave and a 1 kHz sine wave) produces sidebands at +/- 2 kHz from the harmonics of the basic PWM switching waveform: -

[image]

There are wider sidebands too and these are also at intervals of +/- 2 kHz. These are most likely due to my circuit being an imperfect modulator. So, using a much faster op-amp and, band pass filtering the resultant PWM at 100 kHz, it can be clearly seen that it is a classic case of amplitude modulation at twice the modulation frequency: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I see the switching harmonic now. But I still don't get the sideband part. Is there an explanation with math supported? I find it easier to understand with math.

Comment: Now that's a little tricky to get to the bottom of mathematically. I'll start by reminding you that the sidebands are due to the PWM modulating waveform. If there were no modulating waveform i.e. the duty cycle was fixed, then there would be no sidebands. What you then have to consider is that the extremes of duty cycle are caused by the peaks of the modulating waveform. At these extremes the formula for the first harmonic contains the value sin(pi.d). So, if d is nearly zero or nearly 1, then sin(pi.d) is a value close to zero. If d is 0.5 then sin (pi/2) is 1........

Comment: ..... thus, the 1st harmonic is amplitude modulated by the modulating frequency. This is AM in exactly the same way as in radio circuits and, I've just realized I've made a small error in my answer regarding the position of the sideband relative to the harmonic - I am correcting it now - I meant to say the side band is shifted from the harmonic by twice the modulating frequency. Hold on.....

Comment: So, if you can follow the maths behind multiplication of sin(x) by sin(y) you will find that the answer involves cos(x+y) and cos(x-y). Where x is the harmonic and y is twice the modulating frequency. This leads to two frequency components at x+y and x-y. But, because it isn't true 4 quadrant multiplication i.e. there is a dc term involved there is also a term at just x. So, three frequency components; one at x, one at x+y and one at x-y. You might need to think about this for a while if you haven't done amplitude modulation theory before.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! It is new to me. I need to read more. However, I have some questions.   <br/> 1. As I understand sidebands is the result of multiplication of two non-linear waveforms. As from your answer above, it seems that the first term is switching waveform and where is the second term? Is it output voltage? d(t) = switching waveform*Vout(t)?  <br/> 2. From the answer above "This happens at twice the modulating frequency i.e. all the harmonics are amplitude modulated at twice the frequency of the modulating waveform.".Could you explain more why twice modulating frequency?..

Comment: ...sin(n*pi*d) = 0 then n*pi*d = m*pi where m is an integer number. I can't figure out how this relates to modulating frequency?  3. For the part relating to 4 quadrant multiplication, dc term, could you send me a link so I can read up about this?

Comment: Can you see that the PWM waveform is being duty cycle modulated (in your question)? The "d" part is the duty cycle and when the modulation amplitude is high, d = (nearly) 1. When the modulation amplitude is low, d = (nearly) 0. Sine of pi *1 = 0 because pi represents 180 degrees. Sin of pi*0 is clearly zero. Sidebands are the result of any two waveforms multiplied together providing they are different frequencies.

Comment: Because harmonics reach minima and maxima twice every cycle of the modulating signal, the effective frequency of that modulation is twice that of the basic modulation signal. For links see the AM wiki article I linked in my answer.

Comment: For the first question, yes I see how duty cycle changes with modulation amplitude. But I think the question is still remained. Where does the multiplication of two waveforms come from here? duty cycle d should be the product of two signal with different frequencies, switching frequency ws and modulation wm. But where from the circuit or block diagram shows that duty cycle is the product of two components? Hope you see what I am confused now.

Comment: The second picture in my answer that shows the spectral content of a rectangular waveform and how it varies with duty cycle IS the reason. Spectral lines have an amplitude dictated by duty cycle. If that duty cycle is modulated (as it is according to your question by wm)  then you have harmonics that are amplitude modulated by wm hence you must have sidebands. I never said this bit would be easy to follow so please do think hard about this.

Comment: If you are able to see that duty cycle is modulated and that this causes an amplitude modulation on spectral lines then you have an AM waveform at each spectral line. Looking for a direct circuit mechanism of multiplication is the bit that is fooling you. There isn't an obvious one (on the face of it) BUT despite this there is one. If it looks like a duck and it quacks then it is a duck - duty cycle modulation produces spectral amplitude modulation - if you see sidebands surrounding a harmonic there IS the equivalent of analogue multiplication occuring (caused by the duty cycle modulation).

Comment: What software did you use for the simulation?

Comment: @m.Alin I use Micro-Cap 9

Comment: Thanks, Andy. In this case fc = 100kHz, fm=1kHz. So the lower sideband fc-fm =99kHz and upper sideband fc+fm = 101kHz? From your picture above it is 98kHz and 102kHz instead. Also, with the duck example, do you mean that we see the output of PWM has sidebands but it is hard to see where the multiplication causing that sidebands?

Comment: Twice the modulation frequency; it has twice when n equals 1 and d varies above and below 50%. If it has feathers, floats on water, waddles on land, has a short neck and makes a quacking sound then, guess what, it's a duck. 98 kHz and 102 kHz is exactly what I said and what I've domonstrated. If you belive the question has been answered to your content then please mark it as accepted. Thank you. BTW, I never expected to see sidebands at twice the frequency of modulation until I did the math so it's also a new learn for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have untuned circuits, you'll simply see the fast-switching signals.

If you have sharply tuned circuits, with resonant frequencies right on a "harmonic", the circuit will respond to the energy in that "harmonic".

If you have sharply tuned circuits, with resonant frequencies halfway between "harmonics", you'll get a messy response, with the ringing perhaps starting and then stopping and perhaps reversing in phase.

If you have low-Q broadly tuned circuits, you'll get a messy response, looking like a bandpass filter being stimulated by a square wave.

Summary: if you go looking for "harmonics" with narrow-band filters, you will think you have harmonics. Radio frontends could be upset with harmonics, but what really is the problem is the strong broadband transients, because that energy causes momentary overload of the first amplifier, and no radio signal gets thru until the amplifier recovers from the overload.